# How to display my app's first page in phonegap android app?

Tags: android, html, cordova, redirect

I am trying to create an app with phonegap. in iOS, my app works properly. but in Android, my app's first page is not working in app and it always launches a system browser.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix2M7XdRN7c&feature=youtu.be&t=4m12s

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0; url=http://www.google.com/">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
    </script>

    <a href="http://www.google.com">test link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried many ways for fix it. ex) use 'meta tag', 'window.location.replace', and 'window.location.href' ...

but my app still launches a system browser just in an android platform.

Please let me know, how can i display my first page without launching a system browser.

Comment: Do you mean something like the in-app browser? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser  This question needs more information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the config.xml ?

`<content src="index.html" />`

Comment: Ok, but you tried changing for other example file : "main.html" this does not solve your problem?

Comment: I have just one page.(index.html)